# Connection Strings in local exe.config removed (using EF)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, connection-string, app-config

Imprtant note: this is only happening on clients, not in dev environment

I'm having an odd issue.  An application I have written / deployed at my company uses 3 connection strings within it to query data from various sources as needed.  Every so often, I get an error report from one of the end users machines stating something like

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   No connection string named 'CM_PS1Context' could be found in the application config file.

So, I went to this machine, opened up the exe.config file, and sure enough, 2 of the connection string entries were just.... gone.  I went to my machine, grabbed the entries from my config, dropped them in, everything was working again.

I can't make heads or tails of this, nothing in my code is modifying the app.config (user.config, yes).  I am using EntityFramework for all 3 databases.  Has anyone seen this, or maybe has an idea of what might be happening?

Note, this is not happening to all clients, it seems very very random at the moment, as I am unable to reproduce the error myself (nor can anyone if they are trying)

For the moment, my fix is going to be something retarded like watching for that error and when it occurs, reinsert the connection string, but... that's a very messy, ugly fix, that I'd prefer NOT to put in production.  Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: I have no idea how it would change, but setting the file to read only might stop who/whatever is modifying the file.

Comment: Some times you can have multiple app.config for release, debug, etc. Check that you are deploying to all the clients the same compiled application. (just build with release and check the app.config for release, you should add the connections string here too). Do you have multiple app.config files?

Comment: I'm pushing out only the release build, and the MSI contains the correct config file.  As I said, this is only happening to some clients, not all.  When it installs, the config file is correct.